# Microsoft Edge User Agent Overrides without plugin or dev tools

Tags: microsoft-edge, chromium, user-agent, group-policy, microsoft-edge-chromium

Is there a way to change the user agent string in Microsoft Edge version 87 without using a plugin or dev tools? I'm looking at the User Agent Overrides config (under edge://compat/useragent) and it would be great if I could add an entry there.

Else, is there a way to configure the user agent string via group policy objects?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is now way you can change user agent string other than devtools. Please see more details https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/52086552.html

Comment: I don't find other ways to override Edge user agent other than using devtools. I think there's no way to configure it via gpo. All the Edge policies are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies) and there's no one related with overriding user agent. Maybe you can refer to [this script](https://gist.github.com/thorsten/148812e9cc4fb6a19215ce22afd4e5a8) to override user agent, but it only works on certain page that you have executed this function.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. Cheers